# X-Y scatter chart with just 1 or 2 points

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an Excel VBA macro to draw X-Y scatter charts.  The macro works if there are three or more X-Y points to be plotted, but does not chart points properly for only 1 or 2 points.

Below is the macro I recorded for a spreadsheet with three points, and the macro for two points.  The macros appear to be identical except for the ranges for three points and 2 points.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("A2:B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSource Data Source:=Range("Test!$A$2:$B$4")
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
    Range("A2:B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Test!$A$2:$B$3")
End Sub
```

The test spreadsheet has points at (10,10), (20,20) and (30,30).  The 3-point macro plots the points correctly. When the 2-point macro is run on the first two points the chart has only one point at X = 10 and Y = 20.

Answer (score 1):

Excel always has to "interpret" what you mean when you give a range of data for a chart, deciding what goes on the X and Y axis. When you give three or more points in a two-dimensional range, the default interpretation is that the X-values are in the first column (A) and the Y-values are in the second column (B).

For a chart with only two points, Excel (for some reason) is interpreting that the X-values are in the first row (A2:B2) and Y-values in the second row (A3:B3). So you have to "force" Excel to interpret your data the way you want. Use the `PlotBy` parameter:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Range("A2:B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Test!$A$2:$B$3"), PlotBy:=xlColumns
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, Peter T.  This worked with a simple example, but did not work for the more complex macro I am using in my Excel VBA code.  I would include the more complex macro, but can't figure out how to include it in this comment.

Comment: For a more complex example, you should open it in another (new) question. Be as complete as you can and show a set of sample data, the code, describe the expected result, and your question on how to solve the problem you're faced with.